# Power BI REST API - is there anyway to get data of report pages?

Tags: python, powerbi

Hi currently I am following powerBI documentation and to get pages of report I am using this api

https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/reports/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/pages/ReportSection

this api is returning me

```
{'@odata.context': 'http://url/v1.0/myorg/groups/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/$metadata#pages/$entity', 'name': 'ReportSection', 'displayName': 'Test ,report': 0}
```

So this is all I can get till now.I want all data in pages like graphs data or images or any kind of data . is this possible or any workaround exist?I am using python to access these urls. Thanks in advance